# Skiasharp Export canvas to image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, skiasharp

I have a question.
I have a skiasharp canvas with a few bitmaps. Now I want to export the canvas with the bitmaps to an Image, but I have no idea how to do that, or if that is possible.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Show your code so that when someone answers they can replicate your code and include the answer to make your life easier!

Comment: There is no code to show, because I am asking if something is possibe!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably looking to take a [Snapshot of the Surface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/SkiaSharp.SKSurface.Snapshot?view=skiasharp-1.68.1).

```
using (var image = surface.Snapshot())
using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 80))
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(FolderPath, "1.png")))
{
    // save the data to a stream
    data.SaveTo(stream);
}
```

This is very similar to MShah's answer, but just from a snapshot of the surface instead, given that `surface` is a reference to your Skia Surface.

Answer (score 3):

1. To convert the bitmap to image:

   ```
   using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(yourBitmap))
   using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 80))
   {
   // save the data to a stream
   using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(FolderPath, "1.png")))
         {
            data.SaveTo(stream);
          }
   }
   ```

   **Edit:**
2. To convert canvas to png:

   ```
   SKImage mainCanvasImage = surface.Snapshot();
   SKBitmap TempTIFbitmap1 = SKBitmap.Decode(mainCanvasImage.Encode())
   ```

   Use the above code from point 1 to save this.

hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: No, I want to convert the whole canvas to an image. The canvas contains multiple bitmaps!

Comment: @Vreesie If you have multiple bitmaps draw on single canvas then you can capture that surface snapshot. Please find my edit.