# Send picture via Xamarin with WhatsApp

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, whatsapp

I using Xamarin to develop application.

How can I send picture via WhatsApp to number the I have in contact?

Comment: You can refer to this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716565/c-sharp-xamarin-saving-image-and-sharing-on-whatsapp).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [Xamarin.Essentials share API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android)

This will not only give you an option for WhatsApp but many other supported applications as well.

You might need different permissions based on OS so make sure to go through the docs thoroughly.

Add the using statement:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

Get a file from the File system and share it:

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
Title = Title,
File = new ShareFile(file),
PresentationSourceBounds = DeviceInfo.Platform== DevicePlatform.iOS && DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet
                        ? new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 20, 0, 0)
                        : System.Drawing.Rectangle.Empty
});
```

Where File is the path of the file from your file system.

Make sure to check other amazing things available in Xamarin essentials.

### Update

Android:

```
        Intent share = new Intent();
        share.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
        share.SetType("image/jpeg");
        share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, yourImageUri);
        share.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
        StartActivity(share);
```

Comment: Thank about your answer. But I need API to WhatsApp...